# Work done in assembling a continuous system having some charge density is always positive

Tags: electrostatics, energy, charge, work, coulombs-law

The work done in assembling a continuous system having some charge density is given as the   $$W=\frac{\epsilon_{0}}{2} \int E^{2} d \tau$$  which is always positive.

Does this mean no matter what configuration of shape and charge density I choose, the work to assemble will always be positive?

In the discrete case of point charges this isn't the case, we may have positive or negative work depending on the configuration

Answer (score 0):

Electric field energy would be an integral of energy density over volume.  If we assume that the universe is electrically neutral, then all electric fields are a combination of dipole fields.  You do positive work, which goes into field energy, when you separate the + and – charges of a dipole, but negative work if you bring them back toward each other. (The field energy is always positive, but it may be increasing or decreasing.)